# windows: copy with hardlinks for backup

Tags: windows, powershell, backup, rsync, backup-strategies

in case I accidentally modify/delete important documents, my linux PC makes daily backups with a script that gets executed by cron and contains the following line.

```
rsync --checksum --recursive ${source} ${dest}/$i --link-dest=${dest}/$((i-1))
```

(${source} ist the path of the documents folder, ${dest}/n is the path of the n-th backup.)

Using the `--link-dest` option has the great advantage, that if you backup a 3 GB Folder, change on small file and backup again, both backups combined need 3 GB disk space, instead of 6 GB if I would run rsync without the `--link-dest` option.

I'm struggling to write a similar script for windows: I could just use the `cp -r` powershell command (or the xcopy cmd command) but this command does not have an option that is similar to rsync's `--link-dest` option. Using the linux subsystem for windows for the rsync command works, but scripts in the cron.daily folder inside the linux subsystem for windows do net get executed daily.

TLDR: What is the windows equivalent of `rsync -r pathA pathB --link-dest pathC`

PS: In case anyone wants the linux version of the script for his own backups, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/home/username/documents
dest=/myBackup

if [ "$1" == "--install" ] ; then
    echo "installing..."
    cp $0 /etc/cron.daily/myBackupScript
    mkdir $dest
    echo "installed"
    exit 0
fi

for i in {0..9999}; do
    if [ ! -e ${dest}/$i ]; then
        echo "Copying to " ${dest}/$i
        if [ -d ${dest}/$((i-1)) ]; then
            rsync --checksum --recursive ${source} ${dest}/$i --link-dest=${dest}/$((i-1))
        else
            rsync --checksum --recursive ${source} ${dest}/$i
        fi
        DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d__%H:%M:%S`
        touch ${dest}/$i/$DATE
        exit 0
    fi
done
echo "unable to do backup"
exit 4
```

Comment: there are windows versions of rsync

Comment: [cwrsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync) or [deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) works pretty well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create file hardlink in PowerShell on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863258/how-do-i-create-file-hardlink-in-powershell-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

The current `rsync` version (3.2.2) from the [MSYS2 collection](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) for Windows (install: `pacman -S rsync`), supports the `--link-dest` hardlink re-use option correctly on NTFS. It also supports NTFS unicode filenames now.
Absolute paths have to be given in MSYS / Cygwin convention - e.g. `/C/path/to/source/`.

*Note: So far (2021-02) the MSYS2 rsync cannot create / replicate symbolic links in the destination using any of the symlink options. It would create content copies instead. Yet it can detect and exclude symlinks in the source.*